# Generate valid XML name in Java

Tags: java, xml

Are there any helpers that will transform/escape a string to be a valid XML name ?

Example, I have the string `max(OfAll)` and need to generate some XML like e.g.

```
<max(OfAll)>SomeText</<max(OfAll)>
```

That's obviously not a valid name, are there some helper methods that can transform the string to be a valid xml name ?

(For comparison, .NET have some methods that the above xml fragment would be:

```
 <max_x028_OfAll_x028_>SomeText</<max_x028_OfAll_x028_>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding in your .NET example looks like the one defined in ISO9075. I don't think there is a built-in implementation in the jdk, but this encoding is also used by content repositories like alfresco or jackrabbit for their xml import/exports and query apis. A quick search turned up these two implementations, both available under open source licenses:

- http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/jackrabbit/util/ISO9075.java.html
- http://kickjava.com/src/org/alfresco/util/ISO9075.java.htm

Answer (score 0):

One class which may be of use in other situations is [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) in the apache commons-lang project.  It can escape text for use in XML documents, I'm not aware of anything to escape XML element names.

Could you not generate something more readable such as

```
<aggregation type="max(OfAll)">SomeText</aggregation>
```

There are lots of libraries available to marshall/unmarshall objects to xml and back including [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) (part of the JDK), [JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/), [Castor](http://www.castor.org/), [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any helper methods for that, but rules here http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name are pretty straightforward, so it should be easy to implement one.

Answer (score 0):

As should be clear, normal XML escaping (replacing inappropriate characters with character entities) does not result in a valid XML identifier.

For the record, what you are doing is frequently called "name mangling".